# Send data through f:setPropertyActionListener

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I´m newbie in JSF, I have a `<p:dataTable>` with radio button, I want selection a radio button and push the `<p:commandButton>` then I´ll go to other page and I want to see the select info.

Index.xhtml

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="radioDT"
                 var="emp"
                 value="#{empresaBean.getEmpresaList()}"
                 selection="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}"
                 rowKey="#{emp.CLAVE}">

        <f:facet name="header">
            Lista de Empresas
        </f:facet>
        <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{emp.CLAVE}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Nombre Empresa">
            <h:outputText value="#{emp.NOMBRE}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="AÑO">
            <h:outputText value="#{emp.EJERCICIO}" />
        </p:column>

        <f:facet name="footer">

            <p:commandButton action="#{empresaBean.View}" value="Seleccionar" title="Ir Menu" rowKey="#{emp.CLAVE}" >
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{empresaBean.empresa}" value="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" />
            </p:commandButton>
```

EmpresaBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="empresaBean")
@ViewScoped
@Component
public class EmpresaBean {

    @Autowired
    private EmpresaService empresaService;
    private Empresa empresa;
    private Empresa selectedEmpresa;
    private DataModel model;

    public EmpresaService getEmpresaService() {
        return empresaService;
    }

    public Empresa getSelectedEmpresa() {
        return selectedEmpresa;
    }

    public void setSelectedEmpresa(Empresa selectedEmpresa) {
        this.selectedEmpresa = selectedEmpresa;
    }

    public void setEmpresaService(EmpresaService empresaService) {
        this.empresaService = empresaService;
    }

    public EmpresaBean(){} 

    public List<Empresa> getEmpresaList(){

        return empresaService.getAll();
    }

    public Empresa getEmpresa() {
        return empresa;
    }
    public void setEmpresa(Empresa empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }  

    public String View() {
       // empresa = (Empresa) model.getRowData();
        return "/pages/menu/menuPrincipal?faces-redirect=true";
    }


}
```

menuPrincipal.xhtml (ouput)

```
<h:head>
      <title>Menu Principal</title>
   </h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
     <h:outputText value="#{empresaBean.empresa}" />  
    #{empresaBean.empresa}
    <h:outputText value="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" /> 
    #{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}
```

When I go to the `menuPrincipal`, I see this.

```
com.atorresbr.springapp.model.Empresa@5ea928
```

but I want to see

```
Clave: 123
Nombre: John
Año:2014 by example.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is the output of the toString() method called on your object, to see the output you've described override the toString() method, add a method like the following to your Empressa class, set the property names propely, I was just guessing from your facelets

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Empressa{" +
            "CLAVE='" + CLAVE + '\'' +
            ", NOMBRE='" + NOMBRE + '\'' +
            ", AÑO='" + ANO + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

an example that can be usefull http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Because your empresaBean.empresa doesn't contain text. it is class. h:outputText show only text values.

Comment: For example it must be like empresaBean.empresa.CLAVE